# WinRT stop control having focus on load

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

When my app starts the first textbox has focus. This doesn't really matter when running on a desktop, but when it runs on a tablet it means the onscreen keyboard pops up and obscures half the screen.

How can I prevent any control having focus when the app first starts?

Answer (score 4):

Place a button on your page with an earlier TabIndex:

```
<Button
    IsHitTestVisible="False"
    Opacity="0"
    TabIndex="1" />
```

A few things to note:

- Setting visibility to Collapsed doesn't work since the engine likes to focus the first Visible control
- You need `IsHitTestVisible="False"` so users don't accidentally click it and it doesn't accidentally block clicks to anything else on the page.
- Another control type could work, but it shouldn't be a TextBox since it would still bring up the virtual keyboard.
- Setting `IsTabStop="False"` on your TextBox doesn't work since then it can't get focus at all.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no way to simply remove focus other than setting IsTabStop to false on all controls, but the workaround might be to place an invisible control (e.g. UserControl with IsTabStop set to true and Opacity set to 0) with a lower tab index in your page.

Comment: thanks for the tip....setting IsTabStop to false is certainly the easiest and most convenient option